# Download Gradle Takes Forever And Attribute Android : ... is not allowed here

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-studio-3.5

Since I updated Android Studio and its plugin, the folder structure has suddenly changed and the process is gradle sycn:

```
download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

takes a lot of time, even though the size of the file is only 126mb.

I have validated and restarted. The download was canceled but there is a new problem:

```
Android Attribute: ....... is not allowed here
```

I've opened and closed `AndroidManifest.xml`...but nothing has changed; it's still an error.

I have reinstalled Android Studio many times, deleted the folder associated with Android studio...(hoping to return to 0), but it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. You need to follow the below steps.

1. Start Android Studio
2. Switch the file view from "Android" to "Project" view
3. Delete .idea
4. Delete .gradle
5. Delete all *.iml files
6. "Invalidate and Restart"

Note:- Make sure your internet connection is working properly. if your internet connection not working properly while downloading then this issue occurs